# Half screen view vs viewController

Tags: ios, iphone, uiviewcontroller

I want to make half screen presentation of new views.  I need 3 presentation with different content with different animation from different viewControllers.

How to decide that element I need to use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can think of two possibilities:

- A custom parent (container) view controller. Its view can occupy just part of the screen, and then it can have "children" (the different view controllers) where each child's view goes inside the child's view anywhere you like.

  Here's an example where I have two child view controllers and I swap them for one another while doing a custom animation: https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/master/bk2ch06p320containerControllerCustomAnimation/ch19p631containerController/ViewController.m - the child view controller views occupy only part of the screen
- In iOS 7, there's a new feature: when you say `presentViewController:animated:`, you can use custom animation to place the presented view controller's view on top of the existing content at any location you like.

  I've posted an example of how to do this here: https://github.com/mattneub/custom-alert-view-iOS7 It won't be identical to what you want to do, but it will show you the basic technique. You can download and run it yourself.